# A RenderFlex overflowed by 128 pixels on the bottom

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55L9g.png)

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///F:/App/Market/1.7/flutter_application/lib/src/pages/cart.dart:71:21
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#22d62 relayoutBoundary=up3 OVERFLOWING
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=403.4)
...  size: Size(411.4, 403.4)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

```html
body: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: _con.refreshCarts,
          child: _con.carts.isEmpty
              ? EmptyCartWidget()
              : Stack(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
                          child: ListTile(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                            leading: Icon(
                              Icons.shopping_cart,
                              color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                            ),
                            title: Text(
                              S.of(context).shopping_cart,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(
                              S
                                  .of(context)
                                  .verify_your_quantity_and_click_checkout,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ListView.separated(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          primary: true,
                          itemCount: _con.carts.length,
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return SizedBox(height: 15);
                          },
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return CartItemWidget(
                              cart: _con.carts.elementAt(index),
                              heroTag: 'cart',
                              increment: () {
                                _con.incrementQuantity(
                                    _con.carts.elementAt(index));
                              },
                              decrement: () {
                                _con.decrementQuantity(
                                    _con.carts.elementAt(index));
                              },
                              onDismissed: () {
                                _con.removeFromCart(
                                    _con.carts.elementAt(index));
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                color: Theme.of(context)
                                    .focusColor
                                    .withOpacity(0.15),
                                offset: Offset(0, 2),
                                blurRadius: 5.0)
                          ]),
                      child: TextField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        onSubmitted: (String value) {
                          _con.doApplyCoupon(value);
                        },
                        cursorColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        controller: TextEditingController()
                          ..text = coupon?.code ?? '',
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                          hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                          suffixText: coupon?.valid == null
                              ? ''
                              : (coupon.valid
                                  ? S.of(context).validCouponCode
                                  : S.of(context).invalidCouponCode),
                          suffixStyle: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .caption
                              .merge(
                                  TextStyle(color: _con.getCouponIconColor())),
                          suffixIcon: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.confirmation_number,
                              color: _con.getCouponIconColor(),
                              size: 28,
                            ),
                          ),
                          hintText: S.of(context).haveCouponCode,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Theme.of(context)
                                      .focusColor
                                      .withOpacity(0.2))),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Theme.of(context)
                                      .focusColor
                                      .withOpacity(0.5))),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Theme.of(context)
                                      .focusColor
                                      .withOpacity(0.2))),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your column childrens with Expanded widget like this .

```
  Column(
                      children: <Widget>[

                        Expanded(
                        child : 
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
                          child: ListTile(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                            leading: Icon(
                              Icons.shopping_cart,
                              color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                            ),
                            title: Text(
                              S.of(context).shopping_cart,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(
                              S
                                  .of(context)
                                  .verify_your_quantity_and_click_checkout,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),


                        Expanded(
                        child : 
                        ListView.separated(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          primary: true,
                          itemCount: _con.carts.length,
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return SizedBox(height: 15);
                          },
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return CartItemWidget(
                              cart: _con.carts.elementAt(index),
                              heroTag: 'cart',
                              increment: () {
                                _con.incrementQuantity(
                                    _con.carts.elementAt(index));
                              },
                              decrement: () {
                                _con.decrementQuantity(
                                    _con.carts.elementAt(index));
                              },
                              onDismissed: () {
                                _con.removeFromCart(
                                    _con.carts.elementAt(index));
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        )),
                      ],
                    )
```

Comment: Expanded to Container

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho3PR.png)
The issue has been resolved, but another problem has appeared
There is an empty space that I can no longer press